# Maven não exporta todos jars ClassNotFoundException

Tags: maven, exportação, war

Tenho um projeto web (.war) e ele exporta ALGUNS jars para pasta WEB-INF/lib, como ele não exporta o jar `org.json` e estou recebendo ClassNotFoundException!

Estou utilizando o maven, gostaria de saber como eu forço que seja exportado todas depenicas para pasta WEB-INF/lib, ou para pasta adequada.

Detalhes do erro

```
Allocate exception for servlet login: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException from BaseClassLoader@771510a9{vfs:///opt/syonet/jboss6/server/default/deploy/ModuloAgenda.war}
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
```

Segue pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ModuloAgenda</groupId>
<artifactId>ModuloAgenda</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>ModuloAgenda</name>
<description />
<properties>
    <webVersion>3.0</webVersion>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-JBoss-4.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.enterprise.deploy</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.management.j2ee</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.resource</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.security.auth.message</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.security.jacc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-api-osgi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SP3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CONFLITO COM O PORTAL <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId> <version>1.2.1</version> 
        </dependency> -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp/okhttp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160212</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Estranho, você já adicionou o plugin pra empacotar o war. Qual comando você está usando pra gerar o jar do maven?

Comment: Estou utilizando o myEclipse2015, gero o war por ele mesmo...

Comment: Ahhh, é bugado ele. Usa o maven mesmo: mvn package war:war. Me diz se funcionou que eu coloco na resposta ^^

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra estou usando maven a uns 2 dias, como e onde devo usar esse comando?

Comment: Você usa linux? Se sim vai no terminal, entra no diretório onde está o pom.xml do teu projeto, e roda: mvn package war:war. Se usar Windows, vai em Computador > Botão direito do mouse > Propriedades > Configurações avançadas do sistema > Variáveis de Ambiente. Procura a variável PATH e adiciona o caminho para a pasta bin do maven. Depois é só rodar o mesmo comando: mvn package war:war.

Comment: eu não tinha o maven instalado, vou testar aqui

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: Pera, ele gerou o war na pasta target? É o war gerado lá que você precisa utilizar pro deploy do servidor.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44832/discussion-between-david-schrammel-and-giuliana-bezerra).